# Check if string value is a word

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I'm developing a tool to read an Excel file containing a list of values on the following format:

```
ID    Description
1     AR2 KSRT FAN W32
2     KSK43 SRTS COOLER S324
3     RT7 MARS 0934X
```

The tool splits the description of each item using space as delimiter and then check on a English and German dictionary (txt file loaded into a List of strings when the tool loads) if it's a word.
i.e.:

```
ID    Words
1     AR2
1     KSRT
1     FAN
1     W32
```

If the word has numbers on it or it's length it's below 3, I don't check and assume it's not a word.

I'm using LINQ to split the values of all descriptions and then get distinct values (search each word only once).

```
List<string> distinctValues = dtCheck.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(r => r.Field<string>(columnName).Split(' ').Select(x => x).Where(s => s.All(char.IsLetter)).Where(y => y.Length > 2).ToList()).Distinct().ToList();
```

And then using LINQ again to get all entries with a word on its description.

```
dt = dtCheck.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>(columnName).Split(' ').Any(notNeutralValues.Contains)).CopyToDataTable();
```

Currently this process is taking ~40 minutes, is there anything that I can do to improve the performance?

Relevant information:
Input file has 3.411 distinct "words".
Dictionary file has ~2.000.000 words (including brand names, etc.)

For each word I call the following function:

```
private bool isNeutralLanguage(string entry)
{
    bool neutral = true;
     var match = dict.FirstOrDefault(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(entry.ToLower()));
     if (match != null && match.Any())
        neutral = false;
     return neutral;
}
```

Comment: You can introduce the parallel processing of the words and have a Dictionary which is case insensitive to do the processing fast

Comment: Also is your dictionary a list? If you can have something similar to a dictionary in Python, basically a binary tree, to store the dictionary it would give you faster searches.

Comment: Yes, my dictionary is a List of strings loaded from a txt file.
Thank you for your tips!

Comment: Improvements that you need are better choice of data structure like `HashSet`, `Dictionary`, using Regex for verifying characters and using parallel processing for fast result, as shown in my answer underneath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your aim is to improve performance, take following steps:

- Create a `Hashset` post flattening data and use Regex for knowing whether all values are characters. Also this will remove the requirement for separate `Distinct`, also it is case insensitive by passing `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to the constructor

  ```
   var dataHashSet = new HashSet<string>(dtCheck.AsEnumerable()
                .SelectMany(r => r.Field<string>("columnName")
                                  .Split(' ')
                                  .Select(x => x)
                                  .Where(s => s.Length > 2 && Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"))),StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  ```
- Process the `dataHashSet` in parallel using PLinq as follows:

  ```
  var result = dataHashSet.AsParallel().Where(x => isNeutralLanguage(x)).ToList();
  ```
- In the method `isNeutralLanguage` used for testing, make sure the implementation is as follows:

  ```
  var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  private bool isNeutralLanguage(string entry)
  {
     bool neutral = true;
     var isMatch = dict.TryGetValue(entry,out string entryValue);
     if (isMatch && entryValue != null )
       neutral = false;
     return neutral;
  }
  ```
- It is Case-insensitive, similar to `Hashset` above
- It is `ConcurrentDictionary`, since call is `multi-threaded`
- Neutral check shall be O(1) comparison, not O(N) that you are doing, where you can store the value of a given key as `null`, based on logical requirement and quickly process the boolean, depending on whether Key exist or not.
- Make changes to the `isNeutralLanguage` logic on need basis, I have made some assumptions

These changes will ensure much faster performance in your case, as algorithm is improved and processing is done in parallel